# How to setup AWS sagemaker - Resource limit Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to set up my first SageMaker Studio so my team and myself can run some post processing scripts in a shared environment but I'm having issues.

I've followed the steps in this video(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wiDHCWVrjCU&ab_channel=AmazonWebServices) which are:

1. Select Standard setup
2. Select AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM)
3. Under permissions - Create and select new execution role
4. Under Network and storage - Select VPC, Subnet and Security group
5. Hit the submit button at the bottom of the page.

In the video, he clicks submit and is taken to the control panel where he starts the next phase of adding users, however I'm greeted with this error.

[Resource limit Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4k2g.png)

I've checked my Registered domains under route 53 and it says No domains to display, I've also checked my S2 and I have no instances so I have no idea where the 2 domains being utilized are.

My dashboard, image and Notebooks are all empty so as far as I know there's nothing setup on this Sage Maker account.

Could anyone tell me how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have maximum 1 studio domain per region, by the default limits. Though, it seems like you have two domains already provisioned. Try to delete all the domains through the AWS cli and recreate with the AWS Management Console.

Unfortunately, AWS Management Console cannot visualize more than one Studio domain.

Comment: Thanks, managed to figure this out a few weeks ago but you're advice is spot on. As a tangent, what resources did you use to learn the AWS ecosystem? Its a steep learning curve but I feel like i'm getting there

Answer (score 1):

AWS Sagemaker now supports multi-domain <announced in the Re-Invent 2022, Tested in US-EAST-1 >
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdOMQ.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).